# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to test Android app with Gradle, Robolectric and Travis CI

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, travis-ci

I am always running into `NoClassDefFoundError` when using Travis CI to test an Android application with Robolectric and Gradle.

All tests pass in Android Studio. So I guess it's a Travis specific configuration issue. Any experience in running Robolectric tests with Gradle and Travis?

I've the following .travis.yml:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
  - platform-tools
  - tools
  - build-tools-21.1.2
  - android-21
  - extra-android-m2repository

licenses:
  - android-sdk-license-.+

notifications:
  email: false

script: ./gradlew clean test
```

And the following Robolectric specific build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-SNAPSHOT'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'
}
```

This is my GitHub repo:
https://github.com/a11n/android-travis-test/tree/travis-configuration-test

And this is the Travis log:
https://travis-ci.org/a11n/android-travis-test/builds/49715336

```
de.ad.android.app.MainActivityTest > testLifecycle FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at MainActivityTest.java:19
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at MainActivityTest.java:19
```

It seems the Android dependency cannot be resolved.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**

With --debug flag the log discovers which class could not be found:

```
15:45:33.082 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
15:45:33.082 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
15:45:33.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.getByteCode(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:166)
15:45:33.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:123)
15:45:33.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:95)
15:45:33.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.$$robo$$ActionBarActivityDelegate_7c55_createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:51)
15:45:33.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java)
15:45:33.084 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.$$robo$$ActionBarActivity_eab0_getDelegate(ActionBarActivity.java:557)
15:45:33.084 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getDelegate(ActionBarActivity.java)
15:45:33.084 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.$$robo$$ActionBarActivity_eab0_onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
15:45:33.084 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java)
```

I'll investigate a little bit further in this direction, maybe it's a known Robolectric issue.

**Update 2:**

There seems to be an issue with AppCompat v7. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples/commit/85e21dcde99bc860ad91bcf2b4e3605bc267fcaa

However, I try to remove this dependency and check if Travis build passes then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by AppCompat v7. dependency which seems to be a known issue with Travis CI.

For above's use-case, removing the dependency solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. Can you add next to you app `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
      androidTest.setRoot( 'src/androidTest' )
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Updated build.gradle as suggested. Still failing :-(
By the way: Shouldn't that be the default test root anyway?

Thanks so far, further ideas?

Comment: It should. I checked out your project also got same error. I added lines about source and it works for gradle from command line. Do you have other environment where it is failing except travis?

Comment: No, it's running perfect on my local machine (also from command line) but only failing for Travis. So the same configuration is running for you on Travis or only from command line? Here is the current build log with your suggestions applied: https://travis-ci.org/a11n/android-travis-test/builds/49746299 ...

Comment: It's strange, you see :-) ;-) That's where it's working for me too (even without setting the sourceSets).
Somehow Travis need some special treatment.
Thanks so far.

Comment: Can you try to add --stacktrace and collect log, as well --debug and collect log?

Comment: Tried --stacktrace already, but --debug discovered more details. I updated my post accordingly. It may be related to Robolectric 3.0-snapshot (but still strange it only occurs on Travis).

Comment: But it is better to check on robolectric issues and might be create one